# Solver of a system of linear ODEs with boundary conditions (BVP) in JAVA

Tags: java, numeric, ode

I need to solve a system of linear first order ODEs with boundary conditions in JAVA. I was wondering if any of you know a JAVA package with the capability of solving a boundary value problem? (i.e. a solver using finite differences or finite elements)

The type of equation I want to solve is of the following type:
n''(x) = -Dn(x) + n'(x)/x

I know there is the ode solver of apache commons but it can only solve initial value problems. I have also read about the numerical methods but would preferably use existing code.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Probably set a minimum representative example would help.

Comment: I am searching very generally a package with these capabilities. I think it should be clear which type of ODEs I want to solve... But I can add an exemplary ODE with boundary conditions

Comment: If there is no specific question, there can be no specific answer, however https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Psxt2aUo0Ao

Comment: I know about the numerical methods. The specific question was: "I was wondering if any of you know a JAVA package with the capability of solving a boundary value problem?" There exist such packages for example in scipy. Anyway, thank you for looking for that video, I watched it too.